# The development of the Hecke algebras on the representation.

Tags: reference-request, hecke-algebras

Recently, I am interested in the Hecke algebras, but I'm not very familiar with it. Who can provide me some meterials about the history and the development of the Hecke algebras? Is there any good books or papers about Hecke algebras? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: There are tons of books and papers about Hecke algebras, but I am not sure how many will give the history behind it. Basically, it arises as the endomorphism algebra of a suitable induced module for finite groups of Lie type, but most sources just consider it as attached to a Coxeter group and deals with generators and relations. What sort of properties are you interested in?

Comment: @ Tobias Kildetoft, I'm interested in the latter.

Comment: By the latter do you mean as attached to a Coxeter group and given by generators and relations?

Comment: @Tobias Kildetoft. Yes.

Comment: In that case a good place to start is probably something like Humphrey's book on Coxeter groups and reflection groups.